# The Differentiability of a Piecewise Function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Question :

Consider the following piecewise function, for some constants $a$ and $b$. 
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 
x+\sqrt{x^2+b},& \mbox{if} \quad x > 0 \\
2e^{ax}, &\mbox{if} \quad x \leq 0\\ 
\end{cases} 
$$

(a) Find all values of b such that $f(x)$ is continuous everywhere;
For this part, I think the answer should be $b=4$.

(b) Is it possible to choose $a$ and $b$ so the $f(x)$ is differentiable everywhere? If so, find all such choice of $a$ and $b$. If not, then explain why not.

I tried this :

[image]

How to continue?

**Thank you for your help.**

Comment: What does $f(x) > 2e^{ax}$ mean ? It doesn't define a value for $f(x) $ when $x \le 0$.

Comment: @TomCollinge Corrected

Comment: And what about continuity? Does the function need to be continous in order to be differentiable (at least in $x \to 0$)?

Answer (score 1):

For continuity you are correct, b = 4.

The function $f$ is clearly differentiable at every where other than 0.

To be differentiable requires continuity, so b = 4 is required. Use chain rule to get left and right differentials:

$f'(0-) = 2ae^{ax} = 2a$ and $f'(0+) = 1 + x / (\sqrt (x^2 + 4)) = 1 $ If the two must be the same (in which case $f$ is differentiable at 0), then 1 = 2a, and a = 1/2.

Comment: No need to use first principal?

Comment: If your were asked to then you should form the differentials from first principles, otherwise the chain rule is a well known and understood way to obtain a differential: if $f$ and $g$ are differentiable then you have  {$f(g)$}' = $g'.f'(g)$